# Add a string property to a visual c# linklabel?

Tags: c#, linklabel

I am totally new to visual C#.  Whilst I can sort of manage console apps, I easily get lost when it comes to coding forms.

I am currently making an "app launcher" which reads a text file line by line.  Each line is a path to a useful program somewhere else on my pc.  A link label is automatically made for each path (i.e. each line) in the text file.

I would like the .Text property of the link label to be an abbreviated form of the path (i.e. just the file name, not the whole path).  I have found out how to shorten the string in this way (so far so good !)

However, I would also like to store the full path somewhere - as this is what my linklabel will need to link to.  In Javascript I could pretty much just add this property to linklabel like so:   mylinklabel.fullpath=line;   (where line is the current line as we read through the text file, and fullpath is my "custom" property that I would like to try and add to the link label.  I guess it needs declaring, but I am not sure how.

Below is the part of my code which creates the form, reads the text file line by line and creates a link label for the path found on each line:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   //on form load
    {
        //System.Console.WriteLine("hello!");
        int counter = 0;
        string line;
        string filenameNoExtension;
        string myfile = @"c:\\users\jim\desktop\file.txt";

        //string filenameNoExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(myfile);


        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(myfile);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(line);   //check whats on each line


            LinkLabel mylinklabel = new LinkLabel(); 
            filenameNoExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(line);  //shortens the path to just the file name without extension
            mylinklabel.Text = filenameNoExtension;
            //string fullpath=line;        //doesn't work
            //mylinklabel.fullpath=line;   //doesn't work
            mylinklabel.Text = filenameNoExtension;  //displays the shortened path
            this.Controls.Add(mylinklabel);
            mylinklabel.Location = new Point(0, 30 + counter * 30);
            mylinklabel.AutoSize = true;
            mylinklabel.VisitedLinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            mylinklabel.LinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;



            mylinklabel.Click += new System.EventHandler(LinkClick);


            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();

    }
```

So, how can I store a full path as a string inside the linklabel for use in my onclick function later on?

Many thanks in advance

Jim

Answer (score 5):

Use `Tag` property, then it can be retrieved by casting first parameter of `LinkClick` (`object sender`) to `LinkLabel`:

```
mylinklabel.Tag = line;
```

in `LinkClick`:

```
((LinkLabel)sender).Tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Store full path in `LinkLabel` `Tag` Property, you could get the full path like

```
string full path = myLinkLabel.Tag.ToString();
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from a text file isn't pretty good. You could read from a xml file, then it would be very simple to create the linklabels and other stuff. A xml sample:

```
<Programs>
<Program Name="Calculator" Path="calc">
<Program Name="Notepad" Path="C:\blabla">
</Programs>
```

Then you could make a name variable, and a path variable and load the values from the file. But if your a beginner, then a txt file will also do, but it's a pain to load each line's values from the file.